# Asynchronous android GAE communication using restlet

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, restlet

I would like to repeatedly (every second) ask for the message (object or value) to GAE (if android client did not create or change something there) from another android device. I need to check it pretty fast, but I know that it happens aproximately once in hour.

I use restlet and I don't want to create new thread and poll by get from this thread every second, because this is very battery consuming. I also don't want to use C2DM.

Is it somehow possible to do this? I have found something about NIO nonblocking http connectors here:
 http://restlet-code.1609877.n2.nabble.com/Push-data-from-server-using-a-live-HTTP-connection-td2906563.html

But here is described only the client side and I also don't know if this solution would even be possible to use on GAE and how. Does anyone know more about this approach?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: My reason for not using C2DM is that I would like to make it in restlet and thus be able to easily create client for iPhone later.

Do you think that C2DM is really good solution here? I guess that I'll have to diverse then somewhere in logic if the given client is iPhone or Android and decide if to use C2DM or APNS? Am I right? Is it possible to use APNS with GAE? 

Or should I better try to keep it all in restlet?

Comment: C2DM is being phased out quite soon in favor of Google Cloud Messaging for Android.  You may want to look at Google Cloud Endpoints also.

Comment: yeah, Cloud Endpoints is the real rest API for GAE. Anybody has experienced moving from Restlet to Endpoints? Any improvements? faster cold starts?

Answer (score 1):

As the author of uniqush, I created an entry in the [FAQ](http://uniqush.org/documentation/faq.html) page specific to this question.

> **Can I use uniqush on Google App Engine?**
>
> Yes and no.
>
> If you just want to use GCM on Google App Engine, then there are some code in uniqush-push which you can directly use.
>
> However, because Google App Engine does not support socket connection, there is no way to use APNS. In another work, if you want to setup a server on Google App Engine, you cannot push any notification to iOS devices no matter what software/library you are using.
>
> I did considered to port uniqush to Google App Engine. But because of this fact, I think it may be better to port it until Google let us use client-side socket connections, or provide some way to connect to APNS server.
>
> Again, if you are considering to use Google App Engine as a server for your App, please be aware that you will not be able to push notification to any iOS device right now. If this fact does not bother you, then do it.
>
> Personally, I recommend you to run a server with full control. It is not expensive nowadays. Amazon EC2 or similar cloud products may be a good choice to run uniqush.

As I recommended above, using a (virtual) server with full control would be a better choice if you want to support more platforms besides Android.

If there is any other question, please feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0):

For being future proof I would suggest you have a single push notification service for both kind of devices. You can either build on your own, or leverage something like [uniqush](http://uniqush.org/) or [this](http://remotequeries.com/)

Also the Urban Airship's SDK would be a good option to look at, more details [here](http://www.quora.com/How-does-urban-airship-implement-real-time-push-notification-before-C2DM)

Comment: I'm looking at uniqush and it seams good, but with just few documentation. Do you have some code example how to use it? Are you sure that it really works on GAE?

Urban Airship is extremely expensive thus impossible to use for my purposes.

Comment: I have used none. and these are just suggestions, you can find more. Does that answer your original question?

Comment: Yes it has partially answered my question, thank you, but I am still waiting if I'll get some more specific answer to following part from someone:

Is it somehow possible to do this? I have found something about NIO nonblocking http connectors here: http://restlet-code.1609877.n2.nabble.com/Push-data-from-server-using-a-live-HTTP-connection-td2906563.html

It seems to me as the best solution, but I can't find more about it.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://remotequeries.com) is similar to Urban Airship but only a fraction of the cost. The API allows you to send a C2DM message to a user via a call. After you implement the broadcast reciever, when a user installs the app they are prompted to accept the message. If they accept a token is sent to the C2DM server identifying the user. This token is then used to send them a message via the C2DM platform. The Zend PHP Framework has built in functions for this but if reliability is a concern go with an external provider like Remote Queries or Urban Airship